# How to get community id from lua script in suricata

Tags: lua, suricata, zeek

I am using suricata with community id to correlate zeek and suricata logs.  I need to get the value of community id for each tuple in lua script.
Is there any method to get community id for suricata using lua?

Comment: Please provide more details in order for the question to be answered.

Comment: I would like to know if there is any method to get the community_id from suricata using lua script.   The community_id is added to eve.json.  I need to access the value in my lua function which I call from suricata.yaml.

Answer (score 0):

There is a limited set of Lua functions available in Suricata (cf https://suricata.readthedocs.io/en/latest/lua/lua-functions.html#lua-functions).

If you *really* have to use a Lua script for this, I suppose you could add something locally to your Suri, although that can be a bit convoluted to do, as the community id is only calculated during EVE logs generation.

Extra: if Lua isn't mandatory, `jq` could be of great help for extracting the info you need from the EVE logs, and then you'd have easy access to the `community_id` and much more.